Virtualbox shared folder is shared between host and a single VM?
i was just wondering, is the shared folder shared between host and a single VM or is it a shared folder from host to all VMs ?
I'm asking this question since i used in the past a VM with KaliLinux and i would like
to avoid any kind of possible breach (that is one or few softwares of kali getting out of the vm through the folder).
PS: idk why but Windows went haywire when i tried to do apt update on kali :/

From the vms tag description: "Note: This tag should not, as a rule, be used for Virtual Machines (VMs)." How does your question relate to the VMS family of operating systems: OpenVMS, VAX/VMS, and VAX-11/VMS?
